# How can i make right this store procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have the column `nosologico` that can have this values ps_1111 or amb_1111 or 11111.I wanna capture this value. ps: the noslogico at one execute can have multiply values .I don't know if we need to do one extra  condition there ??
So I have made this store procedure but I don't know how to say if the noslogico has %ps% and  go at first condition etc.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE G_TICKETS_Test(USERIDRICHIEDENTEP IN VARCHAR2, result_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
    rc SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN

    OPEN rc FOR SELECT NOSOLOGICO from TICKET_NOTIFICE

    if (NOSOLOGICO= NOSOLOGICO like %PS%) then
    OPEN rc FOR SELECT DISTINCT  t.ID, a.NOME, a.COGNOME, t.OPERAZIONE
    FROM TICKET_NOTIFICE t, ANAGRAFICA a ,PS_METADATA M
    WHERE t.USERIDRICHIEDENTE=USERIDRICHIEDENTEP and  t.stato = '1' AND   t.NOTIFICATION='0'  AND  t.NOSOLOGICO=M.EPISODIOPSNUM AND M.IDANAGRAFICA=a.ID ;

    elsif (NOSOLOGICO= NOSOLOGICO like %AMB%) then
    OPEN rc FOR SELECT DISTINCT  t.ID, a.NOME, a.COGNOME, t.OPERAZIONE
    FROM TICKET_NOTIFICE t, ANAGRAFICA a ,AMB_IMPEGNATIVE B,AMB_METADATA M
    WHERE t.USERIDRICHIEDENTE=USERIDRICHIEDENTEP and  t.stato = '1' AND   t.NOTIFICATION='0'  AND  REGEXP_SUBSTR (T.NOSOLOGICO, '[^AMB_]+$', 1, 1)=C.ID_AMB_METADATI AND C.ID_AMB_METADATI=D.ID_AMB_METADATI AND D.IDASSISTITO=a.IDASSISTITO;

    else
    OPEN rc FOR SELECT DISTINCT  t.ID, a.NOME, a.COGNOME, t.OPERAZIONE
    FROM TICKET_NOTIFICE t, RICOVERO r, ANAGRAFICA a 
    WHERE t.USERIDRICHIEDENTE=USERIDRICHIEDENTEP and  t.stato = '1' AND   t.NOTIFICATION='0'  AND t.NOSOLOGICO=r.NOSOLOGICO AND r.IDANAGRAFICA=a.ID ;
    END IF;

    result_cursor := rc;

END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have some condition to return a single row of `NOSOLOGICO`  from `TICKET_NOTIFICE` . If that's the case, you may use a scalar variable and use the `IF` conditions.

As always, I suggest you to use the explicit `JOIN` syntax rather than the 
`,` syntax for joins.

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE g_tickets_test (useridrichiedentep IN VARCHAR2,
                                            result_cursor      OUT SYS_REFCURSOR 
) 

IS 
  v_nosologico ticket_notifice.nosologico%TYPE; 

BEGIN 

    SELECT nosologico 
    INTO   v_nosologico 
    FROM   ticket_notifice n
    WHERE  n.useridrichiedente = useridrichiedentep ;

    IF ( v_nosologico LIKE '%PS%' ) THEN 
      OPEN result_cursor FOR 
        SELECT DISTINCT t.id, 
                        a.nome, 
                        a.cognome, 
                        t.operazione 
        FROM   ticket_notifice t, 
               anagrafica a, 
               ps_metadata m 
        WHERE  t.useridrichiedente = useridrichiedentep 
               AND t.stato = '1' 
               AND t.notification = '0' 
               AND t.nosologico = m.episodiopsnum 
               AND m.idanagrafica = a.id; 
    ELSIF ( v_nosologico LIKE '%AMB%' ) THEN 
      OPEN result_cursor FOR 
        SELECT DISTINCT t.id, 
                        a.nome, 
                        a.cognome, 
                        t.operazione 
        FROM   ticket_notifice t, 
               anagrafica a, 
               amb_impegnative b, 
               amb_metadata m 
        WHERE  t.useridrichiedente = useridrichiedentep 
               AND t.stato = '1' 
               AND t.notification = '0' 
               AND regexp_substr(t.nosologico, '[^AMB_]+$', 1, 1) = 
                   c.id_amb_metadati 
               AND c .id_amb_metadati = d.id_amb_metadati 
               AND d.idassistito = a.idassistito; 
    ELSE 
      OPEN result_cursor FOR 
        SELECT DISTINCT t.id, 
                        a.nome, 
                        a.cognome, 
                        t.operazione 
        FROM   ticket_notifice t, 
               ricovero r, 
               anagrafica a 
        WHERE  t.useridrichiedente = useridrichiedentep 
               AND t.stato = '1' 
               AND t.notification = '0' 
               AND regexp_substr(t.nosologico, '[^PS_]+$', 1, 1) = r.nosologico 
               AND r.idanagrafica = a.id; 
    END IF; 
END; 
/
```

Comment: WHERE  t.useridrichiedente = useridrichiedentep ;

Comment: can you please :D

Comment: @IliaTapia : So, what if contains both ps and amb for that userid condition `t.useridrichiedente = useridrichiedentep`  ?

Comment: that what i meant for only a user it has all those " ps"  " amb" "number that is the else condtion" all at once i have done this store procedure but it dosen work correclly i will post now as an answer. maybe the one that you send can be add like a ,, for condition''

Comment: @IliaTapia : Check now. I edited the elsif condition it should be fine now

Comment: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "CCTEST.G_TICKETS_TEST", line 10
ORA-06512: at line 7

Comment: @IliaTapia : That means you have multiple values for that userid. which one you want to chose? If you want any one value, you may use `MAX()` or `MIN()` in the select  or `where rownum = 1`

Comment: i need all the values that that user has, but for this value i take the name and the last name from the same table but with diferent joins as you can see i add a for loop i will edit your answer so you can see better, but even so i just get the desired result

Comment: @IliaTapia : It is meaningless to use for loop. Since you are returning only one output cursor variable, there is no reason it has to do multiple iterations. Please handle it sensibly as you could I can't add much here since I don't have your tables/schema and I already recommended  other options. If you found this answer useful in anyway to you please upvote or accept it. If you have further queries, ask a new question. Thanks.